# How can I use lambda to count the number of words in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, lambda, functools

I'm trying to calculate the number of words in a file using `reduce`, `lambda` & `readlines` in an unconventional way:

```
import functools as ft
f=open("test_file.txt")
words=ft.reduce(lambda a,b:(len(a.split())+len(b.split())),f.readlines())
print(words)
```

This raises an attribute error as I'm trying to split integers (indices). How do I get this code to split the elements of the iterable returned by `f.readlines()` and successively add their lengths (i.e, number of words in those lines) to ultimately calculate the total number of words in the file?

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation. Then write `lambda a,b:a+len(b.split())` and add an initializer too `,0` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying get a count of words in a file, `f.read()` makes more sense than `f.readlines()` because it obviates the need to sum line-by-line counts. You get the whole file in a chunk and can then split on whitespace using `split` without arguments.

```
>>> with open("foo.py") as f:
...     len(f.read().split())
...
1530
```

If you really want to use `readlines`, it's easier to avoid `functools.reduce` in any event and `sum` the lengths of the `split` lines (`sum` is a very succinct reduction operation on an iterable that does away with the distracting accumulator business):

```
>>> with open("foo.py") as f:
...     sum(len(x.split()) for x in f.readlines())
...
1530
```

It's good practice to use a `with` context manager so your resource is automatically closed. Use whitespace around all operators so the code is readable.

As for getting `functools.reduce` to work: it accepts a lambda which accepts the accumulator as its first argument and the current element as the second. The second argument to `functools.reduce` is an iterable and the third initializes the accumulator. Leaving it blank as you've done sets it to the value of the first item in the iterable--probably not what you want, since the idea is to perform a numerical summation using the accumulator.

You can use

```
>>> with open("foo.py") as f:
...     ft.reduce(lambda acc, line: len(line.split()) + acc, f.readlines(), 0)
...
1530
```

but this strikes me as a rather Rube Goldbergian way to solve the problem.